# Sharepoint Document Library not showing all Documents

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library

We are using a [project management solution](https://www.mydock365.com/project-management-solution) to manage all our projects and we have a document library for each projects and each tasks. In this specific project, im sure there are more than 100 documents but i'm only seeing like 25 or so documents, what could be causing this, how do i view the rest of the documents, i've tried to work with settings but that was no help, can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the view is filtering.

Start at your 'all documents' view. Click the dropdown to select 'edit current view' and check the filter section.

Answer (score 0):

A few things you can check:

1. Check if you have proper permission to see all documents. Site collection administrators have access to all contents regardless of unique permissions.
2. Create a new list view in this library to avoid any grouping or filtering applied in other views.
3. The rest of the documents might in the state of drafts that are only visible to creators and site collection administrators.